# Adding block to the specific content

Tags: views, blocks

I want to have the same style of block for similar content type but the matter should be different.

For instance, I have a content type of hotel which has different fields in it and I have created a view for list of hotels. Now what I want to do is display the information of of some field from hotel(say Brochure as pdf) as a block when that particular hotel info is requested, rest as content itself.

I know one way of doing it is creating a custom block and restricting it to particular url. But it is too hectic. Is there a simple way of connecting the field from content to the block to that particular content display?

Personal observation: I have tried to place the block(say sidebar first) of content type in "block layouts". Though it shows up, no luck in placing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with a View.

- Create a new view
- Disable the Page that will be checked by default.
- The view should take as argument the `Node ID`.
- Also add a filter based on the content type
- Then in the view, add the fields you want (File, PDF)
- On the top (+ Add next to Master), you need to add a display as a `block`

Now, you go to `/admin/structure/blocks` and add the block. Filter it by Content Type.

:)

Views module - https://www.drupal.org/project/views